# How I can make Recycle Bin for Database Application?

Tags: database, database-design, recycle-bin

I have database application, I want to allow the user to restore the deleted records from the database, like in windows we have Recycle bin for files I want to do the same thing but for database records, Assume that I have a lot of related tables that have a lot of fields.

Edit:

let's say that I have the following structures:

**Reports table**

- RepName primary key
- ReportData

**Users table**

- ID  primary key
- Name

**UserReports table**

- RepName primary key
- UserID primary key
- IsDeleted

now if I put isdeleted field in UserReports table, the user can't add same record again if it marked as deleted, because the record is already and this will make duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I always use surrogate primary key.

Add a timestamp 'deleted_at' column. When user deletes entry put there current time. Make this key part of your constrain.

In every query remember to search only for records that have null in deleted_at field.

Some frameworks (like ActiveRecord) make it trivial to do.

Comment: I thought about that, this will cause a lot of problems for the Constraints that I put on the tables.

look again after adding more info to my question..

Comment: OK, use timestamp column then :)